# Formula, Circle's perimeter intersects with corners of rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

I devised a formula in order to determine the diameter of circle, so that the circle's perimeter intersects with the bottom two corners of a rectangle, whatever the proportion of the rectangle is (or at least if the width is greater than the height). The formula is as follows, whereby W refers to the width and H refers to the height of the rectangle:

W / H = X
X / 4 = Y
1 / X = Z
Y + Z = F
W * F = Diameter

**Does anybody know a more eloquent way to calculate this or is there a known algorithm to do this more efficiently?**

(Bonus points: Does this formula only work for rectangles that are wider than tall?)

*P.S. I was not sure which kind of algebra this belongs to, so I tagged linear algebra since it would not let me choose algebra; Feel free to change the tags if you know better.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the horizontal width is $W$ and the vertical height is $H$, then we want to fit a circle to this rectangle, such that it passes through the midpoint of the top side and have the two bottom corners on it.  So let's place a coordinate system $Oxy$ with the origin $O$ at the midpoint of the top side of the rectangle.  Then the equation of the circle is

$ x^2 + (y + r)^2  = r^2 $

where the center is at $(0, -r)$ and $r$ is the radius.

the equation of the circle reduces to

$ x^2 + y^2 + 2 y r = 0 $

Hence,

$ r = -\dfrac{ x^2 + y^2}{ 2 y } \hspace{24pt} (*) $

If one of the two bottom corners of the rectangle, right one for example, has coordinates (W/2, -H).  Substituting this into $(*)$, you get,

$ r = - \dfrac{ (W/2)^2 + (-H)^2 } { - 2 H } = \dfrac{ (W/2)^2 + H^2 } {2 H} $

Hence, the diameter is given by,

$ D = 2 r = \dfrac{ (W/2)^2 + H^2 }{H} = \dfrac{1}{H}( \frac{1}{4} W^2 + H^2 ) $

For example for a rectangle of horiztonal width $W = 10 $ and vertical height $H = 2$

the diameter of the circle is

$ D = \dfrac{ 25 + 4 }{2} = \dfrac{29}{2} = 14.5 $

Comment: thanks for your answer, altho im having a hard time understanding it because i am not too familiar with mathematical notation. i should have pointed this out beforehand, but i am using this formula in the context whereby the only known measurements are the Width and the Height of the rectangle; everything else, including everything about the circle is unknown. does your formula work if everything about the circle is unknown? lastly, is it possible that you can write your formula in a single "operation" or as few "operations" as possible like in my question e.g. W / H = X; ((X/4) + (1/X)) * W?

Comment: The simpliest formula for the diameter is $\text{Diameter} = (\dfrac{W^2}{4} + H^2) / H $.  I cannot simplify it any further.

Comment: `(width * width / 4 + height * height) / h`, perfect, thank you so much. is there any significant difference whatsoever between that and this: `width * width / (4 * height) + height`?

Comment: No, there is no difference, it is the same expression written in two slightly different ways.

Comment: thanks my friend